# get the size of each array in this list

Tags: java, arraylist

I inserted these two `ArraysList` into this `List`:

```
    ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
    List list = new ArrayList<>();

    category.add("cat");
    category.add("dog");
    category.add("fish");
    category.add("Hamster");

    number.add(1);
    number.add(2);
    number.add(3);
    number.add(4);

    list.add(category);
    list.add(number);
```

Now how do I get the size of each array in this list?

Comment: `"how do I get the size of each array in this list?"`: what kind of result are you expecting?

Comment: @ernest_k This list is then referred as a parameter to another `class` and does not have access to arrays `category` and `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result object of get method from the list with ArrayList.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(((ArrayList)list.get(i)).size());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this

```
 int sizeOfCategory = category.size();
 int sizeOfNumber = number.size();
```

**OR**

```
    for(Object li : list) {
        System.out.println(((List) li).size());
    }
```

Comment: The second option will not work (actually it gives a compile-time error) with the code from the question since `list` is declared using the raw type `List` (see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511930/2838289) for more).

Comment: The compile-time error is not present anymore. Now the compiler issues the warning: "References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized". But this also applies to the accepted answer. I wonder why the answers here (given by users with >1k reputation) are using raw type since the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) says: _you should avoid using raw types._. Doing one cast isn't even shorter than providing the generic type at declaration of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Check object `instanceOf`, if it is type of `ArrayList` which you added, then down-cast it to `ArrayList` and get size.

```
list.add(category);
list.add(number);
for (Object o : list) {
    if (o instanceof ArrayList) {
        System.out.println(((ArrayList) o).size());
    } else {
         // unknown type
    }
}
```

If you want you can get List item type too.

```
System.out.println("Object is type of " + o.getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the [raw typ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of `List`. You would get it on your own, if you had declared `list` using a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html) `T` for `List<T>` which provides a `size()` method. Using the raw type the interface `List` will return elements of type `Object` - hence there is no `size()` method.

As `list` contains two instances of `ArrayList` there are some candidates for `T` available. For example:

- `ArrayList<?>`
- `List<?>`
- `Collection<?>`

It depends on what you need to do with the inner lists (`category`, `number`). If you need only the size of them then `Collectiion<?>` will be sufficient.

```
System.out.println(list.get(0).size()); // 4
System.out.println(list.get(1).size()); // 4
```

Since the inner lists are using `Integer` and `String` as their types, there is no much they have in common in order to replace the wildcard `<?>`. `String` and `Integer` are both implementing `Comparable` but are only comparable to instance of their own type. Thus declaring `List<Collection<? extends Comparable<?>>> list` will not give any additional value. Hence having `list` which contains both inner lists of different types without a useful common type limits the usability of `list` to cases where you don't need the concrete type of the elements of the inner lists.

---

Further reading: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)